# Why eat bread and drink wine on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, challah-shabbat-bread

Why eat bread and drink wine on Shabbat?
Please help me understand the biblical background.
Thank you

Comment: Short answer ... those were staples.

Comment: @Shalom Wine was a staple?

Comment: The challah symbolises the showbread. Refer also to Vayikra 24:8.

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2974301/jewish/The-Showbread-The-How-and-Why-of-the-Temple-Bread-Offering.htm